# define https for wildcard domains

Tags: https, server

I have a DB of users and I'm dynamically creating pages.  So I'm verifying that the user exists in the DB.  I need one page to be https, but I'm not understanding how to define that.

I have the following:

```
// define subdomain here
$server = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
$sub = str_replace('the14dayreset.com', '', $server);
$sub = preg_replace('%^www\.%msi', '', $sub);
$user = str_replace('.', '', $sub);

if(empty($user)) {
  header("Location: https://14dayreset.the14dayreset.com/order-now1.php");
  exit;
}
```

If I use $_SERVER['HTTPS'], then I lose the subdomain.

What is the best way to do this?

Thanks in advance
Pattie

Comment: What do you mean "to define that"?

Comment: I'm sorry if my use of "define" is confusing.  The comment in in code is define subdomain here, hence my use of the word.  Apologies.

I need a specific URL to be https://subdomain.the14dayreset.com/order-now1.php.

Comment: You know that if you NEED https one one page, then it's more secure to add https to ALL pages: if you don't, then in any insecure page, any malicious actor can replace the secure https link (or the redirection http->https )! Adding https to the whole website make it more secure, more safe for the user, and easier to configure.